# Keras - Number of samples error with multidimensional input

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to construct a (very simple) Keras model as a baseline for a project. I have a list of 3459 numpy arrays of shape (2, 6, 15) as input, and a list of target values (ints as numpy arrays with shape ()). When I try to train the model I get this error:

"ValueError: Number of samples 2 is less than samples required for specified batch_size 32 and steps 108."

The model so far is extremely simple, but I'm having no luck getting it to train:

```
input = Input(shape=(2, 6, 15))
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(input)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
output = Dense(1)(x)

model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
hist = model.fit(
    X_train,
    y_train,
    batch_size=32,
    epochs=10, 
    validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
    steps_per_epoch=(len(X_train) // 32),
    validation_steps=(len(X_test) // 32))
```

I'm currently loading the data from pickle files, and I suspect that the issue might be the array structure of the individual training cases. When looking at one of the arrays in the X_train it has a structure [[[...]...], [[...]...]], and I suspect the code is confusing the outer brackets as the batch container, so it's reading a batch size of 2 as input instead. Just a theory, but I don't know how to address that to check for myself.

Answer (score 0):

The error is indeed due to the way your data is being generated/loaded; there are no errors if you train the model on random tensors with the specified shapes.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll look into the best way to load the dataset.